# "App name" doesn't support image insertation here

Tags: android, gboard

I am trying to enable the Image keyboard support to my app. I followed the guide from this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard and trying to understand this code.

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this) {
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo) {
        final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo);
        EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo,
                new String [] {"image/png"});

        final InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener callback =
            new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo,
                        int flags, Bundle opts) {
                    // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
                    if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastNMR1() && (flags &
                        InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0) {
                        try {
                            inputContentInfo.requestPermission();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            return false; // return false if failed
                        }
                    }

                    // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously.
                    // call inputContentInfo.releasePermission() as needed.

                    return true;  // return true if succeeded
                }
            };
        return InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(ic, editorInfo, callback);
    }
};
```

As we can see, The guide create `EditText` and then `@Override` the `onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo){};` method

but in my case, I already have EditText from my xml file

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/chat_box"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:hint="Type Message"
                android:maxLines="5"
                tools:ignore="Autofill,NestedWeights,TextFields"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
```

which is I can't follow the given code from the guide.

I search the topic to google hoping that there is a full tutorial on how to accept the image to EditText but no luck, the sites always landed to this page https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard so I decided to write a question here hoping for an answer.

I have tried using this code but nothing happened.

```
EditorInfo editorInfo = new EditorInfo();
        EditorInfoCompat.setContentMimeTypes(editorInfo,
                new String [] {
                        "image/png",
                        "image/gif",
                        "image/jpeg",
                        "image/webp"});
        AppCompatEditText chat_box =  view.findViewById(R.id.chat_box);
        InputConnection inputConnection =   chat_box.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo);

        InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener connectionCompat = new InputConnectionCompat.OnCommitContentListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCommitContent(InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfo, int flags, Bundle opts) {
                // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously
                if (BuildCompat.isAtLeastNMR1() && (flags &
                        InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION) != 0) {
                    try {
                        inputContentInfo.requestPermission();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("onCommitContent", "false");
                        return false; // return false if failed

                    }
                }

                Log.d("onCommitContent", "true");

                // read and display inputContentInfo asynchronously.
                // call inputContentInfo.releasePermission() as needed.

                return true;  // return true if succeeded
            }


        };

        InputConnectionCompat.createWrapper(inputConnection,editorInfo,connectionCompat);
```

I thought this is the correct way because I don't see any errors when I ran the app but still, my app doesn't support image insertion seems that my code did not trigger anything.

Can someone knows what is the problem of my code?

**Update:**
*Logcat result*

> 08-13 19:14:27.994 20366-7874/? E/MoreFutures: getOrDefault()
>       java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the mp4 url is empty
>           at ocz.a(PG:99)
>           at ocz.get(PG:75)
>           at abh.a(PG:13)
>           at ofa.a(PG:34)
>           at czb.a(PG:75)
>           at czb.a(PG:74)
>           at dba.a(Unknown Source)
>           at oea.b(PG:5)
>           at ofe.run(PG:5)
>           at jqm.run(PG:25)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1115)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:590)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>           at jqa.run(PG:8)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the mp4 url is empty
>           at dbo.b(PG:40)
>           at dbb.a(PG:20)
>           at fni.a(PG:7)
>           at gde.onClick(PG:23)
>           at des.onClick(PG:4)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19907)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759) 08-13
>   19:14:28.004 20366-20366/? W/ImageInsertUtil: Mime Type [image/gif] is
>   not acceptable when inserting the image 08-13 19:14:28.004
>   20366-20366/? W/ImageInsertUtil: Image insertion failed for
>   commitContent with mime-type image/gif 08-13 19:14:28.004
>   20366-20366/? W/ImageInsertUtil: Share intent [Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=image/gif flg=0x10000001
>   pkg=mgb.com.sdalyricsplus (has extras) }] failed to resolve in app
>   [mgb.com.sdalyricsplus] 08-13 19:14:28.044 20366-20366/?
>   I/ImageInsertTask: Inserted
>   https://media.tenor.com/images/a2dabdadd4abc1a5fc08417cc455f66f/tenor.gif
>   in position=0 and result=FAILURE 08-13 19:14:28.054 960-1911/?
>   E/WindowManager: Window AppOp is 45 Window Package
>   iscom.google.android.inputmethod.latin

Comment: What do you get in `logcat` ? There must be something useful to debug.

Comment: @cantona_7   `Log.d("onCommitContent", "true");` never executed.

Comment: I added the logcat to my post. please see

Comment: your error states `the mp4 url is empty `. I dont see anywhere that you use it. Is that all of your code ?

Comment: @cantona_7 I think that error is came from the Ads.

Comment: U need to create a custom `EditText`, override `onCreateInputConnection()` as per above mentioned dev guide and then use this custom class in your XML.